# Array value initialized in element doesn't show at the mediator level

Tags: polymer

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I expect to see the length of an array I've initialized. However, I see an empty value instead, when I access the data at 'mediator' level.

This code is also in a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/wujaruy/edit?html,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.5.0/lib/">
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>

  <dom-module id="x-container">
    <template>
      <!-- doesn't show the expected value of '3' -->
      <div>In container; # of items:[[listItems.length]]</div>
      <x-list listItems="{{listItems}}"></x-list>
    </template>

    <script>
      Polymer({
      is: 'x-container'
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>


  <dom-module id="x-list">
    <template>
      <div>In x-list 1; # of items:[[listItems.length]]</div>
    </template>

    <script>
      Polymer({
      is: 'x-list',
      properties: {
      listItems: {type: Array, value: [1,2,3], notify: true}
      }});
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <x-container listItems="{{listItems}}"></x-container >

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out; I got bitten by the upper-case issue. Changing

```
<x-list listItems="{{listItems}}"></x-list>
```

to

```
<x-list list-items="{{listItems}}"></x-list>
```

fixes the issue

Comment: you can flag your answer as resolved. Everyone will know that this question has been already answered

Comment: Sure.. SO makes you wait 2 days, however.. before you can accept your own answer.